# How can the slow scrolling of tables in Internet Explorer 10, 11, and some versions of Firefox be fixed?

Tags: oracle-adf

Oracle ADF 12.1.2 - 12.2.1 has an issue that table scrolling moves only a few pixels down at a time whe you move the scroll wheel while the mouse is over a table.

If you use the table scroll bars, it works as expected.

It also works as expected when using Google Chrome to view the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[https://community.oracle.com/thread/3527303]

add "!important" to the CSS property af|table::data-body like this:

```
af|table::data-body {
    position: static !important;
}
```